# detect the identity of the MQTT clients and a Mosquitto broker in IoT scenario?

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I am new to **mqtt** and **IoT**,, using mosquitto broker, tried to extend the broker in java for the IoT application...

Is there any algorithm to detect the identity of a mqtt client and a broker???

Comment: It's really not clear what your asking here, do you mean is it possible to authenticate clients connecting to a broker and similarly ensure the broker you connect to is the one you intended?

Comment: yes. the authentication mechanisum between clients and the broker???? is there such thing possible with MQTT and mosquitto?? plz guide..

Comment: My answer already has a link to the Mosquitto documentation and mentions that the client side will depend on which library you use.

Comment: @hardillb thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about authenticating both the MQTT clients and broker then this is possible using Mutual TLS authentication.

Details of how to configure TLS support for mosquitto can be found in the [documentation](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) for the configuration file.

The important options are:

- require_certificate
- cafile/capath
- certfile
- keyfile

How you configure the client will depend on which library/language you are using

Comment: thanks a lot ,,, m searching for the same.. can u further guide on this topic??? is this bother the energy constrained devices???